# Include a few .so files

Tags: c, linux, makefile, dynamic-library

I'm trying to use a few dynamic library I have written but gcc seems to be unable to find them and I'm not understanding why that is. The files libresistance.so, libcomponent.so and libpower.so are all located in /usr/lib the default location for dynamic libs in Linux as I understand it. So what I'm doing wrong?

**C file**

```
#include <resistance.h>
#include <component.h>
#include <power.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[] )
{
}
```

**Makefile**

```
all:
    gcc `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0` -o elektrotestgtk main.c `pkg-config --libs gtk+-2.0` -L. -lresistance -lpower -lcomponent -Wl,-rpath,
```

Comment: Did you run `ldconfig` after having installed the libraries? And you may want to edit carefully `/etc/ld.so.conf` ...

Comment: Also, better add in your *Makefile* some line like `CFLAGS= -Wall $(shell pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0)` and `LDLIBS=$(shell pkg-config --libs gtk+-2.0) -L. -lresistance` ... At last, you should consider switching to GTK3 for your applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, to be able the compile the program gcc need the .h files and for it to find them they need to be placed in /usr/include.